# "Error: failed to parse properties from" temp directory in Android AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, adt, android-virtual-device

I've done some updates recently and now none of my AVD image files work. For some reason it seems to be dependant on the temp directory in windows, so if that gets deleted then it goes mad. The AVD emulators all have a red cross next to them and the error given is:

```
"Error: failed to parse properties from c:\users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\temp-android-tool\.\.android\avd\Android_2_2_360x480.avd\config.ini"
```

How can I fix my avds so I won't have to keep recreating them? It seems mad that deleting "temporary" files breaks the avds.

- I tried looking for this on Google and Stack Overflow but couldn't find a similar issue.
- There is no repair option for these emulators.
- Restarting ADB using:
  adb start-server
  adb kill-server has no effect.

Comment: maybe you created avds by running avd manager in non-admin mode. Try again by giving administrator privileges. In my pc, AVDs are not in temp directory.

Comment: How do I find the AVD manager which is embedded into Eclipse? I looked in all the directories but couldn't find anything. I always run the separate AVD / SDK managers in admin mode but no idea how to do this from Eclipse.

Comment: You need to install [ADT in eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: Not true, I don't know how I would have got the avd manager in eclipse if it wasn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the location where AVDs are created. [See this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html#DefaultLocation)

As per the above link, default location is home directory of user. It should not be in temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was because of the two AVD managers. There's the one in Eclipse and the one separately. When I started using the Eclipse version I noticed that the image files were missing, so I copied them across. Everything was fine and working until recently when the temp files were deleted. I think I must have copied the avds into the temp folder when I was looking for where to put them for the Eclipse version. So I should have put them in: C:\Program Files\eclipse.android\avd